# How to do payload compression in grpc?

Tags: c++, grpc

I am working on a grpc based application, where the request data could be up to 500KB and response could be bigger, and so I would like to compress the data. I have a hard time finding documents/examples in grpc on how to do it. What does set_compression_algorithm in clientContext do? Do I have to set up something on the server side?

Or should I instead forget about compression on grpc, and do compression/decompression into/out of protobuf messages myself?

Comment: Which language? Are you using C++?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `grpc::ClientContext::set_compression_algorithm` method selects the algorithm to be used for the client call, that is, the data being sent from the client to the server.

At the server side, you can control the compression options *at channel creation time* (that is, to be used for all server calls) via `grpc::ServerBuilder::SetCompressionOptions` (see https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/include/grpc++/server_builder.h), which allows you to:

1. Select which compression algorithms are supposed by the server. By default, all algorithms are enabled.
2. Select which compression algorithm will be used by default for all server responses (provided the peer client supports it. If it doesn't, responses will be sent uncompressed).

For one-off call responses at the server, you can use `grpc::ServerContext::set_compression_algorithm` or `grpc::ServerContext::set_compression_level`. The latter is recommended, as it selects the best algorithm according to the requested compression level that the client is guaranteed to support.

I'll put together hello-world-style examples in the following days. I've created an issue to track this: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/6297 Feel free to ping there. I'm also implementing some low-level logging in order to display some compression statistics, for you guys to be able to assert compression is actually working (otherwise everything is completely transparent).

Comment: Adding some logging about compression statistics will be great. Looking forward to this. Thanks!

Comment: just want to confirm: with ClientContext::set_compression_algorithm, does that mean that the request data will be compressed by the given algorithm? And on the server side, if I set default_compression_algorithm to be, say GRPC_COMPRESS_GZIP, the all the responses to client will be gzip compressed?

Comment: The PR adding extra compression logging info is https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/6305 (it's a tracer, meaning you'd have to launch your binary with the environment variable `GRPC_TRACE` containing "compression". eg; `$ GRPC_TRACE=compression,channel ./your/binary` would run `/your/binary` with `compression` and `channel` tracers enabled. For now, grep for `grpc_register_tracer` to see what other tracers are available.

Comment: about your second comment: yes. You can either set the default algorithm/level (preferably level, as described) at channel creation time or you can also enable it on a per-call basis through the `ServerContext`. The only difference is the channel default applies to all outgoing server calls without having to enable it every time through the `ServerContext`.

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if you found it useful :)

Comment: My test shows the server only ranks its own supported algorithms. Client will fail if server use `grpc::ServerContext::set_compression_level ` which may set to an algorithm client don't support.